# Flyway - EmbeddedMysql failing - SpringBoot Junits

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, flyway

When I am running JUnits, those are executing fine in local but failing in Jenkins Pipeline with below error:

```
SQL State  : 08001
Error Code : 0
Message    : Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
```

Below are pom.xml dependencies:

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.wix/wix-embedded-mysql -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.wix</groupId>
                <artifactId>wix-embedded-mysql</artifactId>
                <version>4.6.1</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.flywaydb/flyway-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Properties of MySQL:

```
spring.jpa.database=mysql
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:2205/?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true

# HIBERNATE
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.proc.param_null_passing=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl


# FLYWAY
spring.flyway.enabled=true
spring.flyway.schemas=test
```

Can anyone please suggest why it failing with above error message when running Junits in Jenkins pipeline?

Comment: When running in Jenkins pipeline it is trying to connect to the DB on localhost. I doubt that you have a DB running in that container accessible via localhost?

Comment: yes, I have created EmbeddedDataSourceInstance for junits. @Markiian Benovskyi

Comment: Assuming you have correct username and password set, the only reason for this issue I can see is the access to the host with DB. Probably when connection to `localhost:2205` triggered from your jenkins instance is not able to access the host